# Is using the word “propaganda” to describe this statement an accurate usage of terminology?

Tags: meaning, politics

I asked this same question on Politics SE, but I believe this is one of the rare occasions where a cross-post is warranted, since the question generated a fair bit of controversy in answers and comments, and possibly needs the more lingual expertise provided by this site in order to approach in a more objective manner.

The definition of propaganda is:

> information, especially of a biased or misleading nature, used to
>   promote or publicize a particular political cause or point of view.

Recently President Trump wrote:

> The FAKE NEWS media (failing @nytimes, @NBCNews, @ABC, @CBS, @CNN) is
>   not my enemy, it is the enemy of the American People!

I used the word "propaganda" to describe this statement, and it was argued that using that word was biased. Since no one can provide factual support for the claim that The New York Times, NBC News, ABC News, CBS News, and CNN News are the

> "enemy of the American people"

it seems that this statement easily qualifies under the definition of "misleading". If you look at the "fake news" claim, while most, if not all, of those large news organizations can be accused accurately of posting a fake news article at some point, it's abundantly clear that the president is attempting to make people believe that anything bad these news organizations say about him is "fake news". How could that possibly not fall under the category of "misleading"?

Nor could anyone provide factually based arguments to suggest that those news organizations are

> "failing"

in fact one or more of these companies presented data demonstrating that their subscriptions have gone up, not down, in recent months. So that claim, too, seems to clearly fulfill the definition of "propaganda" as "misleading" information

> used to promote or publicize a particular political cause or point of
>   view.

So in every way, this statement seems to fulfill the definition of "propaganda". It's clear what I think the answer is, but I know that I'm often wrong, and am certainly no language expert.

**Is using the word "propaganda" to describe this statement inaccurate?** Why or why not?

Comment: Cross post from: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15813/is-using-the-word-propaganda-to-describe-this-statement-inaccurate

Comment: @Josh I'm pretty familiar with Skeptics, and I may be wrong but I'm *skeptical* that it's a good fit there. I'm open to editing the question to remove names and make it about a theoretical situation instead of a real one if necessary.

Comment: Calling anything _propaganda_ is a personal judgement, and therefore there is no objective standard or definition to refer to in terms of "accuracy".

Comment: The news falsely reporting stories on purpose is definitely an enemy to the American people. It is a totally separate question if you believe these outlets are actually doing so. Also, beware the dead cat bounce....

Comment: Whether it's accurate or not... it's loaded and will quickly create polarization.  Besides the objective meaning of the word, there is also the connotation with Marxism-Leninism, which some people overreact to. Use it with care in mixed company.

Answer (score 2):

In the current sense of the word propaganda, as long as you believe that the president's statement is a propaganda, you are at liberty to term it as propaganda.

> "**Propaganda** is a 17c. loanword from Italian, derived from the modL title
>   Congregatio de propaganda fide 'congregation for propagating the
>   faith', at first a committee of Cardinals of the Roman Catholic
>   Church having the care and oversight of foreign missions, and later
>   (late 18c.) applied to any association or movement for the propagation
>   of a particular doctrine. In this extended sense it was sometimes
>   treated as a neuter pl. ( = efforts or schemes of propagation) with
>   singular *propagandum*. **The dominant current sense (usu. derogatory),
>   'the systematic propagation of selected information to give
>   prominence to the views of a particular group; also, such
>   information', first emerged at the beginning of the 20c.**" (From The New Fowler's Modern English Usage)
>
> ---

Answer (score 2):

"Propaganda" generally suggests manipulation or dishonesty.  As distinct from a mere argument or claim, propaganda also generally includes some sort of (deliberate) logical fallacy, such as World War II anti-Semitic propaganda that visually depicted Jews as hook-nosed and ugly (essentially an ad hominem fallacy, as physical attractiveness — even if the depiction were true — has nothing to do with honesty or trustworthiness). It doesn't apply to a mere statement of opinion — *regardless of whether you believe that opinion to be right.*

Trump's claims that the media are dishonest amounts to a statement of opinion — and not (in my opinion) propaganda.

> Nor could anyone provide factually based arguments to suggest that those news organizations are "failing"

Isn't he suggesting that they are "failing" to do their jobs of objectively reporting news? Not necessarily a claim that they're (for example) going out of business.